# Is it useful to pass std::weak_ptr to functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I was reading [this article](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) by Herb Sutter about passing smart pointers to functions. He doesn't mention `std::weak_ptr` and honestly I can't find a good scenario where passing such smart pointer is useful.

Does the function take ownership? Pass `std::shared_ptr`. Does the function just need to operate on the underlying object? Pass a raw pointer or a reference.

So is passing `std::weak_ptr` to functions 100% useless?

Comment: To functions, yes, perhaps, to methods, then it's interesting.

Comment: It really depends on the use case.  A `std::weak_ptr` tells you you don't own the object and it might be gone before you try to acquire shared ownership.  If that's what you want then that is what you should use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So is passing `std::weak_ptr` to functions 100% useless?

No.

Consider this toy example.

```
struct PointerObserver
{
    std::weak_ptr<int> held_pointer;

    void observe( std::weak_ptr<int> p )
    {
        held_pointer = std::move(p);
    }

    void report() const
    {
        if ( auto sp = held_pointer.lock() )
        {
            std::cout << "Pointer points to " << *sp << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Pointer has expired.\n";
        }
    }
};
```

In this example, a member function `observe` keeps the `weak_ptr` passed to it.  This is often called a "sink parameter".

This `weak_ptr` parameter communicates that this passed pointer is **not owning, but reserves the ability to own at a later time**, safely detecting if the pointer has expired.

As a different example, a function that **doesn't hold state** for later could also usefully receive a `weak_ptr` parameter in a multithreaded context where the associated data *might expire*  while the function is doing work.

Comment: This answer is [officially endorsed](https://isocpp.org/blog/2018/12/quick-q-is-it-useful-to-pass-stdweak-ptr-to-functions) by isocpp.org. (Nice!)

Answer (score 3):

If your clients have a `weak_ptr`, and your logic could lock it or not, and is valid regardless, then pass a `weak_ptr`.

As a concrete trivial example:

```
mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
mutable std::vector<std::weak_ptr<std::function<void(int)>>> m_callbacks;

void clean_callbacks(int x) {
  auto l = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
  auto it = std::remove_if( begin(m_callbacks), end(m_callbacks), [](auto w){ return !w.lock(); } );
  m_callbacks.erase( it, end(m_callbacks) );
}
void call_callbacks() {
  clean_callbacks();
  auto tmp = [&]{
    auto l = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
    return m_callbacks;
  }();
  for (auto&& wf:tmp) {
    if(auto sf = wf.lock()) {
      (*sf)(x);
    }
  }
}
```

`clean_callbacks` has a lambda that takes a `weak_ptr`.  It is used to remove any `m_callbacks` whose lifetime has ended.

This code is used in a simple broadcaster where broadcasts happen far more often than listeners are invalidated, so waiting for the next broadcast to eliminate a dead listener is a good strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Weak pointers are useful for holding on to objects that might not be available later on (without extending their lifetime). This means that they are usually used for storing in containers (or variables). One would usually pass a shared pointer until the object is stored and then converted to weak pointers. Then when used they must first be converted to shared pointers in order to check if they are still valid. Thus it's unlikely you will pass a weak pointer except as part of the storage and retrieval process, perhaps in helper functions.

Answer (score 2):

The only benefit I can come up with having a std::weak_ptr instead of a std::shared_ptr as an argument in a function, is that the function becomes responsible for checking if the pointer is valid or not, reducing any checks outside the function.

```
bool function(std::weak_ptr _obj)
{
    if(std::shared_ptr obj = _obj.lock())
    {
        obj->doSomething();
        return true;
    }
    return false
 }
```

With a std::shared_ptr as an argument instead, the check is not needed, but a conversion to std::shared_ptr from std:weak_ptr is required before calling the function. Though if there is a risk a nullptr is passed, that needs to be checked aswell.

```
void function(std::shared_ptr _obj)
{
    _obj->doSomething();
}
```

So, if passing a std::weak_ptr to the function many times, from many different places in the application, I think I would prefer to have std::weak_ptr as argument, making the check in that function, instead of checking everytime outside the function. Naturally you will then get lesser lines of code.

Else though, if normally passing a std::shared_ptr, the check is naturally not needed inside the function, and the check if std:weak_ptr is valid inside the function, will be overhead.